# paramWatchers is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
Vue.directive('example', {
    params: ['a'],
    paramWatchers: {
        a: function (val, oldVal) {
            console.log('a changed!');
        }
    }
});
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        someValue: 1
    },
    methods: {
        change: function () {
            this.someValue += 1;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.27/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-example v-bind:a="someValue"></div>
    <button type="button" @click="change">Change</button>
    {{ someValue }}
</div>
```

Can someone explain why paramWatchers never get called?
The example is basically the one from the docs but I can't figure out why it's not working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While previous answer about naming is correct it doesn't solve your issue.

In newest version 1.0.27 of vue.js, which you use, `paramWatchers` doesn't work.

Here is example with version 1.0.26 where it works https://jsfiddle.net/f9u05755/

And here is with version 1.0.27 where it doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/oz04mztk/

So until they fix this bug in some new release use versions prior to 1.0.27 for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it's a bug but I checked github and didn't see any opened issue...

Comment: You're welcome. I opened it yesterday after checking your question.

Answer (score 0):

You've called it `paramWatcher`. The docs call it `paramWatchers`. Add the S.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I corrected, but the problem stil there.